# Can we set reader, writer, processor types at runtime in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am using the jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin v0.4.7 to generate POJO classes at runtime from a JSON schema.I want my reader should be type of pojo class which is generated dynamically.
for instance there is schema of employee.which will be converted to pojo class at run time as Employee.java this pojo name I want to set a type of my reader as ItemReader<'Employee>.
Is there any way which through we can set the type of reader writers at run time in spring batch?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you really generate those classes during runtime, there's no way to refer to them (with `ItemReader<Employee>`) during compile time, because they don't exist.

However, I doubt that you need to generate classes during runtime. Maybe you can show us more code so that we can see what you are doing. But so far, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas:thanks for answer. from schema I know the class name of pojo which will be generate at runtime.only the thing is I am not getting how to set that name as a type of pojo class at runtime .
What I want to do is read fields from schema then create mongodb query from that fields and fetch data from mongodb write it into file. so in this case for mapping purpose i need pojo class which through I can write data according to schema.I have one pojo class according to mongo db data.but i want to write only those field which is specified in schema.so i go for generate  run time pojo class according to schema.now i am able to generate it.I know that name before it will create.I just want to set that class as a type of reader as ItemReader<'pojo_class>
below is my code.

```
    JobParametersBuilder paramBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    readSchema.readSchema(new File("c:/chaitanya/employeeSchema3.json"));
    readSchema.printFields();
    String keys=readSchema.getQuery();
    String mainClass=readSchema.getSchemaName();
    schemaToPojo.createPojo(file,mainClass,package);
    paramBuilder.addString("b", keys);
    paramBuilder.addString("query", "{}");
    Job job = jobRegistry.getJob("mongoToJsonJobBatch");
    JobExecution execution;
    execution=jobLauncher.run(job,paramBuilder.toJobParameters());
```

here in create pojo I am passing three parameters
i.schema file
ii.class name which will generate at runtime `enter code here`
iii.package name.where that pojo class is get created